# What are the considerations when using an advertising slogan, song lyric, etc. in the title of my paper?

Tags: publications, copyright, legal-issues

I've noticed that in economics and business, people often use catchy or interesting titles for their papers. I was wondering specifically about the use of references to song lyrics, slogans, TV shows, movies, literature, etc. in paper titles. For example,

- ["Dancing with the Stars: Innovation Through Interactions"](https://www.nber.org/papers/w24466) references [the TV show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_with_the_Stars_(U.S._TV_series))
- ["Hazed and Confused: The Effect of Air Pollution on Dementia"](https://www.nber.org/papers/w24970) is a pun on [a movie name](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106677/)
- ["Too Much Ado about Morgan’s Men: The U.S. Securities Markets, 1908-1914"](https://economics.yale.edu/sites/default/files/yale_mt_03_2015.pdf) is I believe [a Shakespeare reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Much_Ado_About_Nothing)

My question is, are there specific legal or ethical considerations when appropriating text from (or making references to) someone else's cultural content? For example, could I be sued for copyright violation, or for misrepresenting the original work? Or is this just poor practice generally?

Specifically, in my case I want to use a tag line from a popular ad campaign. A comparable example would be: ["Got Milk? The impact of Heifer International’s livestock donation programs in Rwanda on nutritional outcomes"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0306919213001814). The one key difference is that the ad campaign was produced by one of the companies discussed in my paper.